# Does data types limits have any effect on database space or performance?

Tags: firebird, firebird2.5

I have fields defined as `integer` and other defined as `numeric (8,4)`, while it is enough for the first to be `smallint` and the second to be `numeric (3,4)` so I am just curious to know if I changed or reduced the data type limits of these fields will have any effect on db space or performance ?

Comment: in the long run it saves you space but it's not that significant. The performance will be pretty much the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `NUMERIC(3,4)` is not possible (scale has to be between 0 and the precision). Internally Firebird uses either a `SMALLINT`, `INTEGER` or `BIGINT` for `NUMERIC` and `DECIMAL`. For a precision up to 4 it uses `SMALLINT` (`INTEGER` for `DECIMAL`), 5 to 9 uses `INTEGER` and 10 to 18 uses `BIGINT`. A `SMALLINT` is smaller than an `INTEGER` (2 bytes vs 4 bytes), so it could take less space in storage.

Now if this is something that actually saves storage space or improves performance is a bit hard to tell; Firebird applies a form of Run Length Encoding on the stored record, and a prefix-compression in indexes. This makes it harder to make a definite statement about it, although I'd expect a choice for `SMALLINT` (and `NUMERIC` with scale <= 4) to actually save some space. And of course the decompressed in-memory image of the record will be smaller.

As always with performance (and this case: storage): you need to make non-trivial tests with real (or a good approximate) data to be sure. You should also ask yourself if it really matters for your specific application and usage. You can spend a lot time optimizing (or testing) something that is not really important or relevant.

Another reason for choosing smaller datatypes would be the limited size of a Firebird record (64 kilobyte total, where blobs only count for 8 bytes each), using smaller types could mean having room for additional columns.

However - IMHO - the ultimate reason for choosing a smaller datatype should be that you don't need a larger type and you want to express that limitation in the choice of datatype.